# Angular jasmine test case for for loop (Error: Expected $.length = 11 to equal 3)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing test cases for loop in angular (jasmine) and getting `Error: Expected $.length = 11 to equal 3.`. For loop suppose to create array of array as in `const result`. Can anyone please tell what I missed here?
app.ts

```
loadImages() {
  const rawData = this.data.images;
    for (const value of rawData) {
      for (const image of value.imageData) {
        const v = [value.title, value.documentName, image];
        this.collections.push(v);
      }
    }
}
```

app.spec.ts

```
it('should run the loop and push into imageCollection', () => {
      const rawData = component.data.images = [
      {
        'title': 'First Document',
        'documentName': 'Kad',
        'imageData': [
          'one.png',
          'two.png'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'Second Document',
        'documentName': 'Kad',
        'imageData': [
          'three.png'
        ]
      },
    ];
    
    for (const value of rawData) {
      for (const image of value.imageData) {
        const v = [value.title, value.documentName, image];
        component.collections.push(v);
      }
    }
  });
    const result = [
      ['First Document', 'Kad', 'one.png'],
      ['First Document', 'Kad', 'two.png'],
      ['Second Document', 'Kad', 'three.png']
    ];
    expect(component.collections).toEqual(result);
```

Comment: why do you have for loops inside of a test?

Comment: Im new to test cases. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: I mean, you are duplicating logic from the code inside of a test. that just makes no sense.  you should 1) initialize data(you did it already 2) call method `component.loadImages()` and 3) make the assertions (you also have it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your test to call your method and assert that what it does is accurate.

Something like this:

```
it('should run the loop and push into imageCollection', () => {
     component.data = {}; // set data property to an object
     component.data.images = [ // populate the images property of the object
      {
        'title': 'First Document',
        'documentName': 'Kad',
        'imageData': [
          'one.png',
          'two.png'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'Second Document',
        'documentName': 'Kad',
        'imageData': [
          'three.png'
        ]
      },
    ];
    
    component.loadImages(); // call loadImages
    const result = [
      ['First Document', 'Kad', 'one.png'],
      ['First Document', 'Kad', 'two.png'],
      ['Second Document', 'Kad', 'three.png']
    ];
    // ensure loadImages is doing what it should be doing.
    expect(component.collections).toEqual(result);
```